# Julia - Defining a function that outputs a function

Tags: function, closures, output, julia

I'm trying to create a small function to define the Hamiltonian flow if inputted the functions the Hamiltonian consists of. E.g. I would like to define

```
function makeThedH(f::Function,g::Function)

dH1(s,u) = cos(u[3]).*f(u[1],u[2]);
dH2(s,u) = sin(u[3]).*f(u[1],u[2]);
dH3(s,u) = dot( [1,2] , g(u[1],u[2]) ).*f(u[1],u[2]).^0.5 ;
dH4(s,u) = dot( [1,2] , g(u[1],u[2]) );
dH(s,u) = [dH1(s,u), dH2(s,u), dH3(s,u),dH4(s,u)];
return dH;

end
```

to give be a function dH that I could use in an ODE solver. (Forget whether or not that system is well defined or anything).

Can't seem to find any documentation for functions outputting other functions like this. Thank you for any help ~

Edit: It does return a dH, but I can't seem to use it like a normal function e.g. dH(1,[1,2,3,4]) just returns the object (I think?) dH but doesn't evaluate anything.

Edit: Thanks for helping me realize I should put in the input types, that I would like f,g to be function handles.

Comment: Your code contains logical errors, and doesn't seem to use the `s` parameter at all in its definition, but is otherwise valid code which outputs a "function" (a closure, to be exact, which is a lambda and can be called normally). E.g. you would call it as `dh = makeThedH(1,2)` and then `dh(1, [1,2,3,4])`, and if there weren't errors in your definition for `dh` then this would work as expected. Why do you think this isn't correct syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the input Tasos. It needs the $s$ parameter because the ode solver needs it to have that input (even though it's not dependent on it). As for calling the function, forgive me as I think I should have given input types. f and g should read as f::Function, g::Function instead. When i call dH(1,[1,2,3,4]) it doesn't output any number, it just says there's a dH created and that is it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want seems to be a closure.

In your case, the general idea should rather be:

```
function makeThedH(f,g)
    # optional initial stuff (initializations if needed)
    function dH(s,u)
        # stuff (body of your dH function)
    end
end
```

Comment: he's doing the same thing, he's just using inline syntax (or whatever it's called) instead.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! This worked for me (up to some minor caveats). Not sure why this works and the in-line function defining didn't, though. But, it is cleaner this way (I guess?). Some bug I came across that was strange was that I wanted to make a dH that could be 2 different sizes depending on the user input (like an extra true/false input). Under "true" I would define one form of dH and return it, and under "false", another one and return it. However, it kept just always returning the latter one ("false"). Anyways, that is a separate issue, thank you very much for helping resolve this one!

Comment: @AaronChen in `if` statements, you have to use anonymous functions, since `if` statements don't have their own scope. Also your inline stuff should work, as long as there are no logical errors in the code.